# Delete all rows except max(timestamp) on each day in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to delete all rows except the max(timestamp) per currency, of each day. So the query must only keep the most recent row per currency, per day.

Data

```
Id,currency,value,timestamp
21,btc,8000,2018-07-25 23:00:00 --> Keep this row
20,eth, 800,2018-07-25 23:00:00 --> Keep this row
19,btc,7999,2018-07-25 22:00:00
18,eth, 799,2018-07-25 22:00:00
17,btc,7998,2018-07-25 21:00:00
16,eth, 798,2018-07-25 21:00:00
15,btc,7997,2018-07-24 23:00:00 --> Keep this row
14,eth, 800,2018-07-24 23:00:00 --> Keep this row
13,btc,7996,2018-07-24 22:00:00
12,eth, 799,2018-07-24 22:00:00
11,btc,7995,2018-07-24 21:00:00
10,eth, 798,2018-07-24 21:00:00
```

Latest (max(created_at)) row per currency, per day

```
SELECT
  t.currency
 , DATE(t.created_at)
 , MAX(t.created_at)

FROM `tbltest` t

GROUP BY 
   t.currency
 , DATE(t.created_at)
```

I can find the latest (max(created_at)) row per currency, per day, but how do I only keep those ones, and delete all the other ones?

**solution**

Since the highest timestamp also has the highest id, the simple solution used was the following:

```
DELETE FROM `tbltest` 
WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT MAX(id) 
       FROM (select * FROM `tbltest`) as t2 
   GROUP BY currency, DATE(created_at))
```

Comment: `DELETE DROM tablename WHERE NOT IN([your max query])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row with the highest timestamp appears to also have the highest Id.

```
DELETE FROM YourTable
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM YourTable GROUP BY currency, DATE(timestamp))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rownumber to do the trick. Like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Currency,
         Timestamp,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Currency ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) AS RowNumb
  FROM Table
)  

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RowNumb > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A subquery returning the row to not delete would help you :

```
DELETE FROM table_test
WHERE Id <> (SELECT last.id 
             FROM table_test last
             WHERE cast(last.created_at as date) = cast(table_test.created_at as date)
             ORDER BY last.created_at DESC
             LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 ...` is not MySQL syntax. You mean `SELECT ... LIMIT 1`

Comment: @Kaii Ok, thank you, I will update it. He had it tagged as SQL Server yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to select the max timestamps per currency and day and exclude these from the deletion:

```
delete from tbltest
where (currency, created_at) not in
(
  select currency, max(created_at)
  from (select * from tbltest) t
  group by currency, date(created_at)
);
```

I consider this quite readable, which, in my opinion, is important when writing SQL.

The line

```
from (select * from tbltest) t
```

is strange admittedly. It is because MySQL rejects updates where you query the same table directly. In other DBMS you'd simply write `from tbltest` instead.

If you like it better, you can change

```
where (currency, created_at) not in
(
  select currency, max(created_at)
```

to

```
where (currency, date(created_at), created_at) not in
(
  select currency, date(created_at), max(created_at)
```

which does the same thing of course. Choose the version you find more readable / intuitive.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following sql statement

```
Delete from tbltest
Where t.currency <>
(
  Select temp.currency
  From
  (
    SELECT Top 1 t.currency, DATE(t.created_at), MAX(t.created_at)
    FROM `tbltest` t
    GROUP BY t.currency, DATE(t.created_at)
    order by (max(created_at)) desc
  )temp
)
```

Let me know if it works! :)